# Can i resend mail in java?

Tags: java, email

I have an project use email notify when it finished process.
But sometimes when my computer lost connection to internet, so my process get exception and stop...
So i search the solution of resend the email in JAVA, but i didn't find it.

Does anyone know? JAVA api? or other method~

Thanks for your help!

```
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();

        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

        Session session1 = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
            }
        });

        Message mailmessage = new MimeMessage(session1);
        mailmessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        mailmessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        mailmessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailmessage.setText(text);

        Transport.send(mailmessage);
```

Comment: why don' you push your messages in activemq queue?if something happened activemq will take care.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Because that doesn't give you anything a SMTP server wouldn't do anyway, but adds a lot of unneeded complexity?

Comment: Yeah, for that you also have to make connection of your queue with smtp server, flow would be from java code to activemq queue nd then smtp server.so instead of making direct connection with smtp you should use activemq as an interface. It will improve your performance.

Comment: i'll try to use activemq queue. Thank you for providing directions.

Answer (score 1):

Install SMTP service on computer, then set `mail.smtp.host` to `localhost`.

The SMTP service will attempt to resend email, until it gives up (configurable).

Comment: so i use my computer as a SMTP server?

Comment: @EGary You'll just be using your machine as an SMTP relay server, only allowing relay from local apps, i.e. it won't be open to spam hackers.